# Cannot create PlaceTokenizer class

Tags: java, gwt, mvp

Good day to everybody! I'm trying to create a project based on google's tutorial example for "GWT Development with Activities and Places" article.I have created several places and inside each of them a Tokenizer class. When I try to compile project, I receive the following errors:

```
Found type 'com.calendarmvp.client.mvp.AppPlaceHistoryMapper'
     [ERROR] Annotation error: cannot resolve  com.calendarmvp.client.place.GreetingsPlace$Tokenizer
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.calendarmvp.client.place.GreetingsPlace$Tokenizer
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.TypeOracleMediator.resolveAnnotationValue(TypeOracleMediator.java:750)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.TypeOracleMediator.resolveAnnotationValue(TypeOracleMediator.java:689)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.TypeOracleMediator.createAnnotation(TypeOracleMediator.java:498)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.TypeOracleMediator.resolveAnnotation(TypeOracleMediator.java:648)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.TypeOracleMediator.resolveAnnotations(TypeOracleMediator.java:663)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.TypeOracleMediator.resolveClass(TypeOracleMediator.java:809)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.TypeOracleMediator.addNewTypes(TypeOracleMediator.java:439)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.TypeOracleMediatorFromSource.addNewUnits(TypeOracleMediatorFromSource.java:52)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationState.assimilateUnits(CompilationState.java:164)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationState.<init>(CompilationState.java:82)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:450)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:370)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:360)
at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:252)
at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:233)
at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:145)
at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:232)
at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:198)
at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:170)
at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:177)
   [ERROR] Annotation error: expected class java.lang.Class, got null
```

My GreetingsPlace class is such:

```
public class GreetingsPlace extends Place {
  private String GreetingsPlaceName;

  public GreetingsPlace(String place) {
    this.GreetingsPlaceName = place;
  }

  public String getGreetingsPlaceName() {
    return GreetingsPlaceName;
  }

  public static class Tokenizer implements PlaceTokenizer<GreetingsPlace> {

    @Override
    public String getToken(GreetingsPlace place) {
      return place.getGreetingsPlaceName();
    }

    @Override
    public GreetingsPlace getPlace(String token) {
      return new GreetingsPlace(token);
    }
  }
}
```

AppPlaceHistoryMapper is such:

```
@WithTokenizers({
    HelloPlace.Tokenizer.class, 
    GoodbyePlace.Tokenizer.class,
    GreetingsPlace.Tokenizer.class, 
    ManagerPlace.Tokenizer.class,
    UserPlace.Tokenizer.class
    })
public interface AppPlaceHistoryMapper extends PlaceHistoryMapper {
}
```

Maybe I am missing something... Can anyone help me? Thank's in advance!

Comment: Did you compile the code with 'javac'? Looks like the same issue as this [one](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/ad60dd83580f03f1).

Comment: Thank's a lot!I forgot to rebuild project before GWT compile having automatic rebuild turned off in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You Sholud add GWT Project into classpath in Eclipse 
Run configurationi (classpath under User Entries) 
klikd button "Add project.." and check Your GWT Project. 
Apply Run configuration
and Run

Othere settins are

Main class: **com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer**

Arg: za CodeServer klasso
Program Argumennts: **-bindAddress 0.0.0.0 com.ajna4taiga.recycling.YourGWTModule** 
VM Arguments: -Xmx1024m

Classpath should also have src of your GWT project
classpath 
**User Entries
Advance (button)
Advance folder (add src directory of your GWT project)
Applay Save run configuration**

Classpath should also have 
**gwt-servercode.jar gwt-dev.jar gwt-user.jar validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar mgwt-2.0.0.jar**

mgwt if you have mgwt project of Daniel Kurka. If you have just gwt proje then you don't
need mgwt-2.0.0.jar